# Can I center some cells in a table and left align others?

Tags: html, css

I'm a really really new beginner.  I have been tasked with making an email signature by my boss and I cannot figure out how to produce it.  I'm using dreamweaver and have written really basic HTML emails that sent successfully, so my code isn't the absolute worst.

I'm trying to recreate this (made in word):

[image]

**I want the four lines to the right of the logo to be left-aligned, and the bottom two lines to be centered.**  I don't have any alignment defined in table {} or tbody tr td {}.

Here is how it looks in the chrome preview:

[image]

I will comment to show you how it looks in dreamweaver

in style:

```
    table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

    tbody tr td {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: bold;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.B {font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.smallcaps {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left !important;
}

.bcorp {
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}

.pad {
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    }   

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

And in table>tbody:

```
<tr>
        <td width="96" rowspan="6"><a><img src="http:///wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Logo-01.jpg"  alt="Logo" width="96" height="90"/></a></td>
      <td height="1" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="9" colspan="2"><span class="B">Name Here, Position Title</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20" colspan="2"><span class=smallcaps>Company Name</span>.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="20" colspan="2">12345 SW 22 P<span class=smallcaps>kwy</span> | P<span class=smallcaps>ortland</span>, OR 97111 | S<span class=smallcaps>te</span> 123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="7" colspan="2">D<span class=smallcaps>esk</span>: 503.123.4567 | C<span class=smallcaps>ell</span>: 503.987.6543</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="1" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" cellpadding="5">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img class="pad" src="small-icons-03-03-[1].jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img class="pad" src="small-icons-03-03-[1].jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img class="pad" src="small-icons-03-03-[1].jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img class="pad" src="small-icons-03-03-[1].jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
      <img class="pad" src="small-icons-03-03-[1].jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/"/>
      </a>
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><span class=bcorp>A Certified B Corporation®</span></td>
      <td width="101">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Edited: added code - hope it's clear enough to help

Comment: Please include the code of your html here and Css

Comment: You can apply alignments via adding `style` attribute to your `table` and/or `td`... If you can post some of your codes, maybe we can see what causing your issue was.

Comment: https://ibb.co/igKuyv - Dreamweaver preview

Comment: @DaniP I figured out how to add the code correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, please check this and see if this will help you. About the table issue.
Some Email program don't render Inline-CSS to the body of email. You may consider use the `style` attributes to support what Table design is missing. I used to do this when generating newsletter.

```html
<table width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:#EEE;font:small-caps 400 14px sans-serif;color:#444;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" align="center" width="125" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">Logo Here</td>
          <td style="line-height:1.6;padding: 5px 15px;">
            <div>Name Here, Position Title</div>
            <div>Company Name</div>
            <div>Stress address wrapped around here</div>
            <div>Desk: 123.456.789 | Cell: 123.456.789</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <table align="center" width="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td> <a href="#">Icon1</a> </td>
                <td> <a href="#">Icon2</a> </td>
                <td> <a href="#">Icon3</a> </td>
                <td> <a href="#">Icon4</a> </td>
                <td> <a href="#">Icon5</a> </td>                
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            A Certified B Corporation <sup>&reg;</sup>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this doesn't stay formatted in outlook.  The icons get stacked vertically in stead of horizontally :/  But it looks great in other previews.

Comment: I see. You can do alternative with another table inside the `td` and center the alignment of the `table` inside of it. Please see the updated version of the table format.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the required alignment in the cells using CSS properties: text-align:center and text-align:left. By the way, a row defaults to text-align:left so if you don't put the alignment then it by default goes to left alignment.

And for merging the cells, you can use rowspan and colspan attribute in the  tag inside HTML.

I am posting a working example with complete CSS and HTML code for your consideration here: https://jsfiddle.net/rahuldhangar/0s5usofv/

HTML code:

```
<table width="400" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:#EEE;font:small-caps 400 14px sans-serif;color:#444;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" align="center" width="125" bgcolor="#DDDDDD">Logo Here</td>
          <td style="line-height:1.6;padding: 5px 15px;">
            <div>Name Here, Position Title</div>
            <div>Company Name</div>
            <div>Stress address wrapped around here</div>
            <div>Desk: 123.456.789 | Cell: 123.456.789</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <ul style="list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;">
              <li style="display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;"> Icon </li>
              <li style="display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;"> Icon </li>
              <li style="display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;"> Icon </li>
              <li style="display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;"> Icon </li>
              <li style="display:inline-block;padding:0 5px;"> Icon </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            A Certified B Corporation <sup>&reg;</sup>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
```

Comment: When I use the text-align functions it goes all or nothing, that's why I tried the '!important' bit to try to make it override.  I need to have some cells be centered and some aligned left.  It can do either all centered or all left, but not a mix - thus my question.  Thank you for your effort though!

Comment: iMarkDesigns has given a well formed code hence making my answer less relative :) Hope I would be of some help next time!

Comment: I am wandering on how to insert "Run Code Snippet" button in the answer? Anyone? :)